# Can't return final value async.map

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async.js

I am trying to return the final value of `async.map` instead of console.logging. Unfortunately the `return` statement is never run:

```
var square = function (num, doneCallback) {
  return doneCallback(null, num * num);
};
// **Works**
async.map([1, 2, 3, 4], square, function (err, results) {

  console.log("Finished!");
  console.log(results);
  // return results;
});


// **Not Working**
async.map([1, 2, 3, 4], square, function (err, results) {

  console.log("Finished!");
  // console.log(results);
  return results;
});
```

How can I `return` results instead of using `console.log`?

Comment: Why are you using `async.map` if you want to return the results? Use `Array.prototype.map`

Comment: The `return` statement is run. But `async.js` is intended for use in asynchronous code, where the return value doesn't get used, so it doesn't do anything with it.

Comment: BTW, you don't need the `return` statement in `square`. Just call the callback.